# Why does `Allocator.allocate` hand out `NonNull<[u8]>`... but `deallocate` accepts `NonNull<u8>`?

Tags: rust, std, allocation, alloc

As the title says.

```rs
pub unsafe trait Allocator {
    fn allocate(&self, layout: Layout) -> Result<NonNull<[u8]>, AllocError>;
    unsafe fn deallocate(&self, ptr: NonNull<u8>, layout: Layout);
}
```

The two required methods on an `Allocator` both take different pointer types, this seems weird to me. Why has that choice been made?

Furthermore, why are `u8` and `[u8]` chosen at all? Why not just have `NonNull<()>` or `NonNull<[()]>` for both methods?

My understanding is that choosing `[u8]` or `u8` is a fine idea because it has the least-strict layout requirements that can actually be allocated (since `Layout` requires `align` to be non-zero). But, I think requiring a cast *every time* could be a better design choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The allocator might over-allocate, and `NonNull<[u8]>` is a fat pointer including length information.

Why `u8` rather than `()`? Not sure, but it probably reflects the idea that all memory is a bunch of bytes in the end. Also the fact that pointers to ZSTs are allowed to dangle might have something to do with it.

Comment: Good point about the fat-pointer, didn't think of that. And then having `deallocate` take a fat pointer as well doens't make any sense!